# Распределение трафика

Tags: сервер, администрирование, веб-сервер, dns

Уже задавал подобный вопрос здесь, но все же нужны подробности.
Есть сайт с большой активностью, сейчас он стоит на одном сервере и иногда не выдерживает, появляются в рамках 18 - 21 по МСК лаги. Нужно сделать собственный сервер с распределением трафика, для будущего улучшения.
Схема распределения трафика должна быть такой:
1. Первый сервер с уклоном на производительность отвечает за полную версию сайта.
2. Второй сервер так же с уклоном в производительность отвечает за мобильную версию сайта.
3. Третий сервер с уклоном на быстрый обмен файлами, FTP, хранение данных ( Картинок ).
Схема действий от лица пользователя: Клиент заходит на сайт, его перенаправляет на один из первых двух сервером, исходя из устройства пк, мобилки. Далее подключившись к серверу, идет запрос на получение файлов из третьего сервера ( Картинки ).
На руках есть железо, домена .com .ru, сеть в 500 мб.сек, как мне реализовать подобное? 
Был бы благодарен за подробный ответ с ссылками и примерами. Спасибо.

Comment: Если особо не заморачиваться:
делаем три ДНС A-записи с разными IP адресами.
первая - полная версия (скажем поддомен www.), вторая - мобильная (поддомен m.), третья запись - на ресурсы (поддомен files.)

Но вообще лучше сделать по-другому. Один внешний айпи - на нем будет nginx. В зависимости от запроса он будет редиректить его на два остальных сервера. Что мы получаем? Масштабируемость.

Comment: в чем принципиальное различие раздачи мобильной и обычной версии?

Comment: добавлю к @Etki будет ли это вообще решением чего либо, если процент мобилок не указан. Разобрались бы вы сначала в причинах лагов, и указали бы их в вопросе.

Comment: Полная версия и мобильная ( Адаптивная ). Лаги как раз таки из-за перегрузки. Сначала думаю как раз таки разделить трафик на 2 основных сервера а далее уже добавлять сервера к той и другой группе по мере нагрузки.

Comment: @gecube из этого мы масштабируемость не получаем, только гибкость. Файлы сами по себе не умеют масштабироваться, приложению тоже уметь надо.

Answer (score 2):

Ваш посыл вполне понятен, но никуда не годится (если не забуду - чуть ниже отпишу, почему). У вас есть проблема производительности, основная хотелка "нужно, чтобы не было лагов", выродившаяся в дополнительные хотелки "сервак под А, сервак под Б, сервак под Ц". Но это все остается хотелками (бизнес-целями, если хотите), но не предложениями по реализации и устранению проблемы.

Формально у вас есть два подхода к решению проблемы производительности. Первый, дешевый, состоит в закидывании проекта железом (масштабирование), второй, дорогой, состоит в непосредственном устранении проблемы. По мере роста компетенции разработчика он учится решать проблему вторым путем, но так или иначе есть пределы, продуктивнее которых приложение физически не заставить работать (или бессмысленно заставлять с точки зрения ресурсов, которые нужно потратить), и дешевле закидать проект дополнительным железом. Судя по описанию проблемы я уверен, что на самом деле все проще и лучше решить не через масштабирование, а через непосредственные правки кода, тем более что вы уже собрались разделять файлы, приложение и мобильное приложение, а надо-то просто поработать в паре мест.

Само масштабирование бывает трех видов. Обычно говорят про вертикальное масштабирование (увеличение мощности серверов с приложением) и горизонтальное масштабирование (увеличение количества серверов и разнесение нагрузки между ними). Третий путь, который не совсем относится к масштабированию, дорог и не всегда возможен - это разделить приложение на подприложения и разнести на разные сервера (это то, чем вы собрались сейчас заняться). Если у вас горит, проще всего отмасштабироваться вертикально и взять тайм-аут на решение проблем с архитектурой. Касательно предложенной схемы - вот почему она не взлетит:

- Вы собираетесь вносить правки в приложение "прямо сейчас". Это грозит знатным техническим долгом, большими затратами и нулевым выхлопом, за исключением печального опыта.
- Мне не очень понятен "уклон в быструю раздачу файлов". Физически-то это как? Купить ssd? Если да, то зачем для этого отдельный сервер?
- Предположим, после переезда на сервак с мобильным приложением перешло 5% нагрузки, чего основной сервак не заметил. Puff, столько работы и все впустую.
- И, наконец, зачем вообще делить мобильную и обычную версию, если они отдают одинаковый контент, и, следовательно, будут иметь одни и те же вызовы и тормоза?

В любом случае, чтобы бороться с тормозами, вам нужно выяснить, **что именно** тормозит. Без этого вы можете (и собираетесь) потратить кучу ресурсов впустую. Вам нужно начать с аудита, выявить реальную причину потери производительности, а не саму проблему, и только потом подумать, как ее решить. Вы сейчас собираетесь сделать следующие вещи:

- "Отмасштабировать" статику выносом на отдельный сервер. Предположим, что проблема в статике - в этом случае тормоза никуда не денутся, а тратите вы уже в три раза больше. А добавить сервер для статики просто так не получится - нужно либо равномерно делить статику между серверами, либо хранить на каждом сервере полную копию всей статики. И в первом случае приложение не знает, с какого сервера ему забирать конкретный файл, во втором вы окунетесь с головой в проблему нахождения неотреплицированных файлов в массиве на 500 гб.
- "Отмасштабировать" приложение. Оно к нему готово? Вы готовы к тому, что на мобильном приложении и а обычном будут разные пользовательские сессии? Что если скрипт создает файл во время запроса А, то запрос Б для работы с этим файлом придет на совершенно иной сервер?

Подводя итог всего вышенаписанного, я бы рекомендовал:

- Провести аудит, нарисовать схему приложения, выявить критические места (что не масштабируется? что тормозит под нагрузкой? что отвалится под нагрузкой?), найти тормоза
- Решить проблему торомозов из кода. Поверьте, она там, современные процессоры обрабатывают просто невероятные объемы данных в секунду, если им отдать правильный код.
- Подготовить приложение к горизонтальному масштабированию, чтобы в следующий раз не городить огород.
- Перенести всю работу со статикой в облако (Amazon S3, Swift и аналоги). Это спасет ваши сервера от файловых запросов (можно будет брать меньше диск и сеть) и от вышеописанных проблем с масштабированием статики (дайте этому заняться S3)
- Поставить дешевый сервер с Nginx / HAProxy в качестве прослойки, которая будет обслуживать пул серверов приложения. В случае аларма вы сможете добавить в этот пул еще один равнозначный сервер, чтобы горизонтально отмасштабироваться.

"В целом" такие проблемы решаются именно пулом равнозначных серверов с одинаковыми копиями приложения. Но сами приложения перед этим, конечно, пишутся с мыслью о подобном использовании.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы прояснили все.